# Update the DNS address for all PCs in a specific domain

Tags: windows-10, dns, ipv4

I'd like to make a script that updates the DNS address on all our windows 10 PCs but only for the NIC that is connected to a specific domain.  The problem is that our PCs have multiple NICs connected to different subnets.  If there a way to assign the DNS to the NIC that is connected to 192.168.16.X or thisdomain.com?

Comment: If you know the interface name you can use `netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.1` (as an example).

Comment: The interface name varies.  One PC may use "Ethernet  2"  while another uses "Ethernet 6".

Comment: Then you will have to parse `netsh interface ip show config`, find the right interface (based on the **current** DNS) and extract it's name. Save the name and use it as described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are the NICs on different subnets? If they are, you can do this via DHCP option 8 on the DHCP server that is assigning IPs.